# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}y \frac{y-1}{e^y-ey}\sqrt{y}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral

$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}y \frac{y-1}{e^y-ey}\sqrt{y}$$

which numerically is equal to $0.1878102975$.

The apparent pole at $y=1$ is integrable as the function is anti-symmetric around this point. It can be seen by expanding the integrand around $y=1+\varepsilon$ and $=1-\varepsilon$.

The best I could do for the moment is the change of variable $-y e^{-y}=u$ which transforms the integral onto
$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1/e}^0 \mathrm{d}u \frac{1}{1+eu}\left(\sqrt{-W_{-1}(u)}-\sqrt{-W_0(u)} \right)$$

where $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ are the two reals branches of the Lambert W function.

Comment: Any simple pole is an integrable singularity with respect to the Cauchy principal value, but you should state that you are interested in $$\mathcal{I}=\color{red}{\text{PV}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y-1}{e^y-ey}\sqrt{y}\,dy.$$

Comment: By playing a bit with geometric series, $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\text{PV}(\ldots) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e^n\,\Gamma(n+3/2)}{(n+1)^{n+5/2}}$$ where the general term of the series behaves like $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e\cdot n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: Using the duplication formule of the Gamma function, it seems that this series interpolates between a Hypergeometric one and a Polylogarithm one, interesting...